# Codeigniter - Show data in HTML table that coming from three tables as array object

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I have three MySQL tables as below, (primary keys are highlighted and foreign keys in italic )

Projects table,

**Projected** | *projectname* | projectdesc

Project structure table,

**Projectstructureid** | *projectid*  | structurename

Project tasks table,

**Projecttasksid** | *projectstructureid* | taskname | taskstartdate | taskenddate | estimatedhours

I have three array objects that are passing to the page,

```
$all_projects - from Projects table,
$all_structures - from Project structure table,
$all_tasks - Project tasks table,
```

And the HTML page is as below,

```
    <table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Project</th>
        <th>Structure</th>
        <th>Task</th>
        <th>07</th>
        <th>08</th>
        <th>09</th>
        <th>10</th>
        <th>11</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
        <?php
          foreach( $all_projects as $project )
          {
            foreach( $all_structures as $structure )
            {
              foreach( $all_tasks as $task )
              {
                echo '<tr>
                        <td>'. $project->projectname .'</td>';
                        if( $structure->projectid == $project->projectid )
                        {
                          echo '<td>'. $structure->structurename .'</td>';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                          echo    '<td> </td>';
                        }
                        if( $task->projectstructureid == $structure->projectstructureid )
                        {
                          echo '<td>'. $task->taskname .'</td>';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                          echo    '<td> </td>';
                        }
                echo    '<td> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                    </tr>';
              }
            }
          }
        ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

My problem is, I am getting a lot of duplicating row as below:

[image]

**My question is:** How to show display Project name, Structure and task along in one row and avoid the duplication?

Comment: Can't you join the tables in one query instead?

Comment: The query what you have written is the only reason why duplicates value coming. Use Join

Comment: Thanks for this will try with joins

Answer (score 0):

Firstly this is codeigniter,
I could fix this using joins in the model, instead if passing separately

```
$all_projects - from Projects table,
$all_structures - from Project structure table,
$all_tasks - Project tasks table,
```

I have created a model like this,

```
function project_structure_task()
{

$this->db->select('projects.projectid, projects.projectname,
          projectstructure.projectstructureid,
          projectstructure.structurename,
          projecttasks.* ')->from('projectstructure')
     ->join('projecttasks', 'projecttasks.projectstructureid = projectstructure.projectstructureid')
     ->join('projects', 'projects.projectid = projectstructure.projectid');

$sql_stmt = $this->db->get();
return $sql_stmt->result();
}
```

and call it on the controller and passing like array,

```
$data = array(  'title'         => 'My title',
                'project_tasks' => $this->timesheet_model->project_structure_task() );

        $this->load->view('template', $data);
```

and use it in the view with use of foreach

```
foreach( $project_tasks as $task )
{ }
```